# At what point does the memory get allocated to a constant variable in c++?

Tags: c++

As much as i know, constant class members must be initialized before the constructor runs, but since they cannot be initialized in the class body (as it is just a prototype), therefore we need to initialize it inside initializer list. My question is when does memory gets allocated to a constant variable, and what is the order of execution?

```
class constant
{
    const int a;
    public:
    constant(int k):a(k)
    {   
        cout<<"a is "<<a<<endl;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    constant cl(5);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Is it true that constant variables need to be initialized at the point where they are allocated memory?

Comment: There is no answer that will apply to all C++ implementations, because it is not specified in the Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea about `const`. Think less of it as related to implementation details (like memory), or runtime, and more there as a means to help the programmer and for the compiler.

It doesn't matter when the memory gets allocated (although it's  before you construct the object, before entering the initializer list - not specified by the standard), what matters is you can only initialize the variable in the intializer list (pre C++11) or even the class definition for `const` integral types.

Comment: Technically speaking, you can allocate memory for an object before initializing it (e.g. with placement `new`).  So "when you construct the object" is inaccurate.  The constant `a` in the example gets allocated at the same time as its containing object.

Comment: No, your exact words are "(although it's when you construct the object, before entering the initializer list - not specified by the standard)".

Comment: I see you've edited, but my comment stands.  "Before you construct the obejct" is overly vague :-)

Comment: @AndréCaron honest mistake :)

Comment: @AndréCaron well, you can't really be too specific with non-standard stuff. Memory *might* not even be allocated....

Answer (score 1):

> when does memory gets allocated to a constant variable

Here, `a` is a data member of `class constant`, so it's allocated *as part of* `constant`. Whenever you create an instance of `constant`, there's an `a` already included.

Note that `static` members are different, but just because `a` isn't allowed to change after initialization, doesn't make its *storage* different from any other regular data member.

> ... is it necessary that constant variables be initialized at the point where they are allocated memory

Strictly, you have to have the memory available before you can call the constructor, so the phrase *at the point where* is a bit problematic (see specifically André Caron's comment about placement new).

However, allocation and construction are tied together in most normal use, and initialization of a const member *must* happen when the object is constructed.

Comment: It could.  An object with static storage duration and no non-const members could possibly be stuffed into read-only memory (if the compiler can prove that nothing reads the value before initialization is scheduled).

Comment: hmm, true: all I meant was that it's storage & allocation aren't somehow determined _independently_ of the containing object

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is `const`, the compiler enforces you to not change that value after initialization. That is, you must initialize it (*must* in the sense of [RFC2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)).

You must directly initialize it:

```
struct constant {
  const int a;
  constant(int k) : a(k) {
    /* everything is fine here */
  }   
};
```

You must not leave it uninitialized:

```
struct constant {
  const int a;
  constant(int k) { 
    /* error: uninitialized member ‘constant::a’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int’ */
  }   
};
```

And you must not change it's value after construction:

```
struct constant {
  const int a;
  constant(int k) { 
    a = k; 
    /* error: uninitialized member ‘constant::a’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int’ */
    /* error: assignment of read-only data-member ‘constant::a’ */ 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact memory place for object members depends from object creation.
If you create object by "new" it is would be a heap.
If you create stack object (like on your example) it is would be a stack memory.
"Constant" memory - it is memory for "constant", not for "const variables".

Other words, const memory used for literal strings, literal numbers ("text", 5), while a const modifier restrict the memory update.